# Architect Java Hashmap Hierarchy to its equivalent in Redis Cache?

Tags: java, caching, redis, memcached

I have the following Job class representing runs of a job. I have a list of start and end times in Job class because the same Job can be rerun.

```
public class Job {

      private final List<Timestamp> jobStartTimes = new SortedList<>();
      private final List<Timestamp> jobEndTimes = new SortedList<>();
      private String jobName;
      private String jobKey;
      private String host;
      ....
      ....
}
```

I have this Map for querying jobs given jobkey.

```
public class JobMap {

         /**
         * Here value of 'String' key is jobKey
         */
         private final Map<String, Job> jobCache;
}
```

I have also created the following hierarchy of hashmaps for storing (starttime, jobKey) and (endtime, jobkey) entries in Map so that I can retrieve job records faster. This is needed because my queries are timestamp based, for ex: return all jobs that ran between x and y timestamp.

```
public class YearCache<T> {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is month number (0, 11)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, MonthCache> monthCache;
}

public class MonthCache {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is week number in a month(0, 4)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, WeekCache> weekCache;
}

public class WeekCache {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is day number in a week (0, 6)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, DayCache> dayCache;
}

private class DayCache
{
        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is hour value in a day (0, 23)
         * T is of type String representing jobKey
         */
         private final NavigableMap<Integer, NavigableMap<Timestamp, Set<T>>> hourCache;
}
```

I want to get rid of this Java hashmaps and move to Redis Cache. How can I model/architect this hierarchy in Redis Cache?